# Implicit to Explicit waits within test c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written a test which has implicit waits for 5 seconds. I've been looking at ways to introduce explicit waits to my code so execution doesn't take as long.

I've seen there's many different ways to introduce explicit way to the code. How would I go about doing this such as below but I'm not sure what the correct way would be for me

```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")));
}
```

/

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='country-selector-btn']")).Click();


            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            IWebElement country = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("country"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(country, "India");
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);



            IWebElement currency = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("currency"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(currency, "$ USD");
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);




            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='save-country-button']")).Click();

            webDriver.Quit();

        }

        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken about how `ImplicitWait` works. You keep calling it like you are expecting it to wait for 5s each time. The `ImplicitWait` timeout is set once for the life of the driver. If you were to remove all instances of setting the timeout except for the first, your script would work exactly the same.

Quick note before I get into explicit waits... the Selenium docs [state not to mix them](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

For explicit waits, you are going to be waiting for something specific... an element to be present, be visible, be clickable, etc. You can take a look at the documentation for [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) and [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) for more details.

A quick example

```
// create a new instance of WebDriverWait that can be reused
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement button = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("someId"));
// do something with button
```

There are a LOT of different conditions that you can wait on already available in `ExpectedConditions` so make sure you get familiar with them. In general, you rarely will need something that isn't provided there so check before writing a custom condition.